# Converting List of Files into JSON array in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am working on an API in ASP.NET. This API is written in C#. I am looking at a directory and I am trying to list each files details as a JSON string. The end result needs to work like this:

```
string json = "[{ name:'picture-1.png', mime-type:'image/png', size: 968 }, { name:'picture-2.png', mime-type:'image/png', size: 2578 }]";
```

In an attempt to do this, I currently have the following code:

```
string jsonArrayString = "[]";

string directory = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/"), "Files");
if (Directory.Exists(directory))
{
  string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "picture*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
  foreach (string filename in fileNames)
  {
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

    string actualFileName = fileInfo.Name;
    string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileInfo.Name);
    long size = FileInfo.length;

    // Add to JSON array?
  }
}  


return jsonArrayString;
```

I do not know what the best way to do this. Everything I'm doing feel like a hack. It seems like there should be an easy way to do what I'm trying. Yet, its clearly something I do not know.

Comment: Don't hand create your own json strings. Use a proper library. [JSON.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is highly recommended. Just create an array of objects of a class with the properties you need and then serialize it.

Comment: Have a class with properties for `name`, `mime-type` and `size`, Create a List of that class objects, add Items to that list in your loop and return serialized List.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON.net

First, create a class like this

```
public class FileInformation
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mime-type")]
    public string mimeType{get;set;}
    public int size {get;set;}
}
```

then

```
var list = new List<FileInformation>();

foreach (string filename in fileNames)
{
  FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

  string actualFileName = fileInfo.Name;
  string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileInfo.Name);
  long size = FileInfo.length;


  list.Add(new FileInformation(){//SetProperties});
}

var yourJSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

that's it

Download JSON.net from the website
    http://james.newtonking.com/json
or via nuget

Answer (score -1):

You need to read the file, add that the content to JSON object.

```
Jsondata.file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Filepath);
```